# "Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution..." error in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I simply changed my package name in Flutter by editing `.xml` and `gradle` file(s) and changing the folder names in `src/main/kotlin/my/package/name`. After that action there is "1" sign in front of Android folder, but it does not redirect me to any file that has an error. I assume the error is in the folder (structure) itself and maybe changing folder names in `/kotlin/` folder caused it.

[image][image]

Answer (score 15):

Uninstalling the "Java Dependency Viewer" extension in Visual Studio Code fixed it for me, and it might be worth a try.

I'm only writing in Kotlin, so I didn't need it.

Comment: thanks for sharing, error suddenly disappeared, why appeared and disappeared is still unknown. thanks for solution.

Comment: I didn't install that extension, instead, I had "Project Manager for Java" extension and disabling it resolved my problem.

Comment: disabled every Java related extension and it worked for me.

Comment: For me it was "Extension Pack for Java"

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Project Manager for Java worked for me.